# jQuery: Adjust the height of the overall container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://dev.clickymedia.co.uk/rdicoursefinder/course-finder/

If you view the link, you will see that there are a number of filters acting at the same time. The overall height of the box is adjusted dependant on the amount of items showing by the filter plugin.

We then have a popup box when you click on each item. This also has a varying height, and pushes the next items down. We need the height of the container to adjust, taking into account the original height of the container before the item is clicked, and the popup box's height.

I have written some jQuery to do this, however, as you will see, each time it is adding the height of the blue popup box to the overall height again and again when you click the item to show the box, instead of once one is showing, adjusting the height of the container accordingly.

The jQuery I have used for the height is below:

```
var originalHeight = $('#filter-results').height();
var thisHeight = 70 + $('.resultsShowing').height();

var overallHeight = originalHeight + thisHeight;
$('#filter-results').height(overallHeight);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, and I agree about the setInterval issue, but how do I go about it adding and removing classes when the filters are adjusted? You will see that the columns (firstColumn etc) are added by classes, and the only way this works is by the jQuery working it out constantly due to the filters.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var originalHeight = $('#filter-results').height();
```

will need to be outside your `click()` event, and should be done only once on `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using the new height every time you're generating more height.

You need to move the `originalHeight` to one specific point, the first time you need it, and leave it alone there. Then, only `thisHeight` needs to get updated, and the result height should bet the former (static) + the latter (dynamic).

Comment: Could you possibly suggest some code to fix this? Many thanks

Comment: Set the `originalHeight` inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});` instead of the click event, then leave the rest as it is.

Comment: I've done that, and as you will see, the height is now not correctly calculated. Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: You have a `var originalHeight = 0;` down the road there, buddy

Comment: Great spot! Thanks, looks like we're nearly there. Any more ideas?

Comment: Looks good to me, what's missing? The extra space at the bottom?

Comment: If use one of the filters, without refreshing the page, you get the big white space at the bottom. With refresh, it works a treat but unfortunately, I can't do this with a refresh. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay, looks like it's using the original height before the filter was applied. I'd suggest to also update `originalHeight` whenever the filter is updated, that way you keep track of the good height when it gets smaller than the full list.

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. Do you know of a way that I can target when a filter has been used? The on click for the ('.rethink a') doesn't work when I place it here.

Comment: What's happening when you update the height on filter update?

Comment: It seems to ignore it. Is there another way I can target the filter change?

Comment: Well I can't really tell how you're targeting it - but generally where the filters update the list should be the place to look, after the list is filtered and loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this first of all

```
window.setInterval(function(){
///etc
}), 1);
```

It's killing my machine in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back to me. Removing this means the columns can't be worked out each time the filter is used, meaning I can't apply css for the blue box each time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just increase the interval time to 100ms instead of 1ms. If you need it quicker 16ms is ~60fps. Looking at it though, it should be an event that is triggered from the use of a filter.

Comment: I've changed that now. If you have any advice into how to get the height sorted that would be excellent. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know the blue element height before you display it, you should create it in memory:

```
var blueBox = $('<div />').html( ... );
var height = blueBox.height();
```

now you can add this height to the overall container and display blue element:

```
blueBox.appendTo('.overall');
```

ps. sorry about pseudo code